# Add text inside an inputbox using CSS

Tags: css, placeholder, inputbox

I cannot edit the html code, is the question below possible using only "CSS" code?
How do you add a text just like a placeholder or something to an inputbox?

Here's the input text box code:

```
<input id="isn_email_address" type="text" name="user" size="40" maxlenth="90">
```

Comment: Why you `cannot edit the html code`? Just use a placeholder!

Comment: if only but the code is a built in, It doesn't show the inputbox code. I only inspect elements the code above.

Comment: You would have to add it to the `input` tag. There's no way to add the text with CSS. You can only style the placeholder with CSS but not change the text.

Comment: Even using content="" don't work? @roope

Comment: in such a case, using script is totally acceptable.

Comment: ` document.getElementById('isn_email_address').placeholder='Enter Email ...'; `

Comment: @zen `content` works with `:before` and `:after`. And it only adds the text before or after the element you select.

Comment: Another Kludge - ` #isn_email_address::before { content: " Enter Email .." } ` and place it absolutely - then hide on ` :hover `

Comment: @RobSedgwick i think this will work only for webkit

Comment: @RakeshShetty , as Zen is asking for ' like placeholder' - Placeholders : http://caniuse.com/input-placeholder  /  Psuedo : http://caniuse.com/#search=pseudo-elements -

Comment: @RobSedgwick ***#isn_email_address*** is an input field, and input field is just an empty element, pseudo-element (`:before`, `:after`) can just be used on container elements, and only on some input fields like `checkbox`, `radio`. In this case the input field is just a textbox and normally we can't use `:before` on it. That's what @RakeshShetty meant, looks like **webkit**-based browsers support it somehow **but** all other browsers don't, so it's not a cross-browser solution.

Comment: @KingKing, yeah sure, he would have to target the container - but Zen gets the idea. In fact ::before on the container would have more support than placeholder, anyways, thanks for the egg suck all the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set placeholders using CSS for all browsers. The only browser that supports it at the moment is webkit.

Using `jQuery` you can achieve this : Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w5ZUe/1/)**

**Note :** you will need latest jquery library you can download from here [jQuery Library](http://jquery.com/download/)

Try this code :-

```
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function()
        {

            $('#isn_email_address').attr("placeholder", "Type your text here");    

        });

    </script>



</head>
```

Comment: Would it still work for webkit even though there is no placeholder attribute in the input tag, would it require the attribute to change it?

Comment: @Rakesh Shetty I was referring to your first paragraph, changing it purely with CSS, sorry for being unclear.

Comment: Thank you very much @RakeshShetty your code really works. I did tried searching the net, maybe i wasn't looking hard enough. I'm still a newbie at these things.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some pseudo elements, assuming you're not supporting IE7 and below.

```
#isn_email_address {
   position: relative;
}
#isn_email_address:after { /*could use :before if you wanted too*/
   content: "Type your text here";
   display: block;
}
#isn_email_address:focus #isn_email_address:before {
   display: none;
}
```

You'll probably need to do some z-index adjustment to make sure that you're able to select the textfield. Additionally, some css *left: /*my value here*/* to make sure it's in the right spot.

Comment: `:before` and `:after` applies to the content of the element. Since input tags has no content therefore `:before` doesn't work with inputs.

Comment: @KheemaPandey good point. Blast. JavaScript solution it is. Thanks for the info too, I wasn't aware of that rule.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a placeholder, obviously there is another way. I don't know whether it's possible with CSS alone. But using JavaScript and CSS you can definitely do that.

Comment: Thats' not an answer, you should improve your answer

Comment: It's pretty easy.So at least let the guy search the internet and do it himself.I've told him how to do it.Please allow him to implement this.I'm all here to help him

Comment: you no need to suggest OP just goolge it. if you have really answer then comeup with real answer.